# Erro chamando webmethod

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webforms, webmethods

Estou criando um webmetod que fara o autocomplete de alguns campos da minha tela, porem estou recebendo erro 500

```vb
        <System.Web.Services.WebMethod>
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False)>
            Public Function AutoComplete(ByVal prefixText As String) As String
                Dim resposta As string =  "funciona"


                Return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resposta)
            End Function
```

como podem ver é bem simples apenas para ver se retorna a mensagem do servidor

Meu javascript

```
function buscaPorParametro(campo) {
            var valorDigitado = $("input[name='" + campo +"']")
            console.log(txtBox.val())
            $.ajax({
                data: JSON.stringify("{  prefixText: '" + valorDigitado.val() + "' }"),
                dataType: "json",
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: onError
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(data) {


        }
        function onError(err) {
            console.log(err);
            $('#LoadingPanel').css('display', 'none');
        }
```

erro retornado do servidor

```
"{"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\u0027","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}"
```

alguém saberia me dizer onde estou errando?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Como na assinatura do seu `Webservice` você espera apenas uma `string`, é exatamente isso que você deveria passar quando consumi-lo via `javascript`.

Ao enviar os dados via `javascript` dessa forma:

```
JSON.stringify("{  prefixText: '" + valorDigitado.val() + "' }")
```

O valor será convertido em algo parecido com isso:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("prefixText","xpto");
```

E ao tentar consumir o seu Webservice, ocorrerá erro de conversão, pois um `IDictionary` não pode ser convertido para `string`.

Sugiro alterar a assinatura do seu Webservice para isso:

```
Public Function AutoComplete(ByVal dados As Dictionary<string, Object>) As String
```

Ou então, envie apenas uma `string` via `javascript`.

Comment: Fala Bruno, cara eu tentei fazer dessa maneira ... e não funcionou, ele diz que por dictionary ser uma implementação da interface IDictionary ele não pode converter o objeto, você conseguiu executar o código assim ???

Comment: Opa, esqueci do primeiro parâmetro do construtor do dictionary. Editei a resposta... da uma olhada

Comment: então eu ja tinha reparado nisso, mesmo fazendo como se deve, o erro aparece no momento de subir a aplicação.

The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

eu acho que a unica maneira de fazer funcionar é tipando um objeto e colocando ele na assinatura do metodo ... provalvemente isso vai resolver

Comment: Coloca string no seu webservice e tenta mandar só assim: valorDigitado.val()

Comment: Fiz de outra maneira olha a resposta, []'s

Answer (score 0):

No fim consegui resolver o problema tipando a assinatura do método

```
 Public Function AutoCompleteCodigo(ByVal _getDados As Dados) As String
```

End Function

e no javascript

```
function buscaPorParametro(campo) {            
        var dados = {};
        dados._getDados = {};
        dados._getDados.Descricao = $(this).attr("Descricao");
        $.ajax({ data: JSON.stringify(dados),
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(data) {

        alert('good');
    }
    function onError(err) {
        console.log(err);
        $('#LoadingPanel').css('display', 'none');
    }
```

onde as variaveis abaixo são a construção do objeto que esta sendo enviado para o webmethod

```
var dados = {};
```

dados._getDados = {};